# Finder Methods Related Controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have two controllers, orders and tasks - each order has many tasks.

In my orders show view, I list all the related tasks for the order.

My issue is that I want to restrict the output - eg. only list tasks with a status = 1

In my orders controller I tried this:

```
 @tasks = Task.find(:all, :conditions => [:status => '1'])
```

But I get an error:

```
undefined method `%' for {:status=>"1"}:Hash
```

I also don't really know how to call this. In my orders show view I tried this:

```
<% @task.tasks.each do |task| %>
  <li>
    <%= task.title %> <%= task.dueddate %> 
  </li>
<% end %>
```

Can you help a flailing newbie :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really need to check query interface in rails 3

http://railscasts.com/episodes/202-active-record-queries-in-rails-3

http://railscasts.com/episodes/215-advanced-queries-in-rails-3

Btwn your solution is:-

```
 @tasks = Task.where(['status = ? ', 0])
```

Comment: jain Hi there, this works fantastic and I've watched the railscasts. What's the best way to do so from another controller? If I want to list tasks from orders, I tried this: @tasks = Task.where(['status = ? AND order_id', false, 1]) ? Jx

Comment: My mistake... Needed to use:     @tasks = Task.where(['status = ? AND order_id = ?', false, 1])
Silly me!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would approach this.

Task Model

```
def Task
    belongs_to :order

    scope :status, lambda { |stat| where(:status => stat) }
end
```

OrdersController

```
def show
    @order = Order.find(params[:id])
    @starting_tasks = @order.tasks.status(1).all
end
```

View /orders/show.html.erb

```
<%= @starting_tasks.each do |task| %>
    <li><%= task.title %> <%= task.dueddate %></li>
<% end %>
```